# How to open a new Terminal with shell prompt and running multiple commands in Command Line?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I want to Open a new Terminal in from within terminal.

It should have Shell prompt as well as already run few commands.

How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax is :

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "[COMMAND 1]; [COMMAND 2]; exec $SHELL"
```

Got from these articles: [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82783),[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11500788) and tested.